# How to change bootstrap link_to color on navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-rails

How to change link_to color on navbar to make it look like this;

```
<a class='brand' href='#'>PROJECT_NAME</a>
```

so far i have

```
.brand
   = link_to "PROJECT_NAME", root_path
```

but its still blue:(

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me ([part of the code is from the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-the_destroy_action)):

```
<%= link_to "delete user", user, method: :delete,
      data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?" }, class: 'delete' %>
```

Then in my custom.css.scss file I have:

```
li {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
    a:link {
      &.delete {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a class to `link_to` element, you need to add it after comma.

```
= link_to "PROJECT_NAME", root_path, class: 'brand'
```

But of my experience of working with Bootstrap, I think, that it won't change your color. So, you need to add `!important` to your `.brand` class in CSS file to overwrite default Bootstrap colors. Or you can hardcode it like this (to avoid `!important` conditions):

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
  &.brand {
    color: #color;
  }
}
```

Comment: it didn't help. i can change font-size in brand class using !important but it doesnt work with color property, dont know why;/

Comment: I've just checked on my bootstrap project. Everything works fine. Does your `brand` belongs to `a` element, not `li`? Can you show your CSS with `brand` and its parent elements? And output of your browser with this link?